# Is the FCM module in fcm-django removed in the latest version version 2.0.0?

Tags: python-3.x, django, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

Is the FCM module in fcm-django removed? I could use the fcm_send_message and fcm_send_bulk_message functions up to version 0.3.11 of fcm-django but in the latest versions the 'fcm' module is missing.

This is my import statement that had been working fine up to version 0.3.11 of fcm-django:

```
from fcm_django.fcm import fcm_send_message
```

How to use those functions in the new versions of fcm-django?